# Disabled designer due to inheriting abstract class?

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio, inheritance, designer

I have a solution with one project. In that project are something live 40 or 50 forms. I've made 4 base forms that all the other forms can inherit. All 4 of those base forms inherit System.Windows.Forms.Form. Almost 90% of the forms inherit one of the first 2 base form. The rest inherits one of the last 2. But now I got this error out of nowhere, I made like 3 progs with the last 2 base forms and while I'm making the 5th, this errors occures and the designer is disabled.

> The designer must create an instance of type 'xxxxxxx.frmBaseCr' but it cannot because the type is declared as abstract.

How an I solve this? I've searched on google for many hours now but I just can't find any working solution. I've tried the #if #else #endif statement but that doesn't seem to be working. I'm working in Visual Studio 2012 Express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `MustInherit` keyword.

Comment: I haven't got any MustInherit keywords in the base or in the inheriting form. I had a MustOverride and I just changed it to Overridable but still the same.

Comment: My apologies, I've found the MustInherit in the designer code. It worked, thanks mate!