# VB.NET, Inherits HttpWebClientProtocol, abstract type error

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, abstract-class

In my project there is a class that Inherits HttpWebClientProtocol, when accessing created instance I get empty reference error and in Visual Studio class itself shows 'The designer must create an instance of type 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol', but it can't because the type is declared as abstract'
I know there is a workaround, but I still need an advice - only started programming VB couple of days ago.

Comment: Did you check out this? <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707158/disabled-designer-due-to-inheriting-abstract-class>

Comment: I've googled your link before asking this question, There is no MustInherit in my class.